# GUI on C in VIsual Studio 2013

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

How to create GUI using C language in Visual Studio 2012/2013? Which libraries I should use and is there some short introductory?

Comment: It's a really bad idea. Microsoft introduced the C++ based MFC, intended to relieve programmers of much of the pain of building GUIs with the raw Win API, more than 2 decades ago, and *it* is pretty much obsolete. Since then they introduced .NET with WinForms and later WPF. Do yourself a big favor and learn C# and WPF.

Comment: @Jim Balter, I know that. But I must do it in C. I possibly can do it in C# or Java, but my customer insist to make it only in C language.

Comment: Well, just make sure the customer understands that it costs more, initially and in terms of maintenance, to write GUIs in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard WinAPI in windows, it let you create simple graphical user interface for your program (but it can be painful)
http://zetcode.com/gui/winapi/ (and especially: http://zetcode.com/gui/winapi/dialogs/ )

Answer (score 2):

For C in Visual Studio, you can use Windows API.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_USER

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383743.aspx

Answer (score 1):

here it is.

Using `C` with `WinAPI` (WinAPI is Application Programming Interface for Windows)

Now i will give you tutorial link.

WinAPI - http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/60793-introduction-to-the-winapi/

Best Regards.

Comment: You should also briefly explain how to use eg. WPF *using C*, since that is the question. Is it really possible?